# MVC 4.0 using Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to set the Label Text which is available on _Layout.cstml from different Controller.

For Example

If I want to navigate from Dashboard to ProductList Page. Then My Label Text on _Layout Page should be "Product List". which I am setting from ProductList Controller Index Method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ViewBag.xyz in _Layout.cshtml. Pass the viewdata from controller action and it will be shown on your html page.

Note:- Please confirm me if you means something else. I will update my answer if this doesn't means what you looking for.

it's look like you want to set the ViewBag.Xyz different different for every controller.

I recommanded you to use ActionFilterAttribute to make it work. The code will something like this.

```
 public class DashboardCustomData : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.xyz = "This is my Dashboard page";
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Now put this Actionfilter to every controller. You need to use different different ActionFilter for every controller which have different title. After doing this you never need to set it manually from every controller.

If you don't like to write the multiple filter then try this one.

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
            string ActionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();

            if (controllerName == "Dashboard")
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.xyz = "This is my Dashboard page";
            }
            else
            {

            }


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

Comment: This is the Label Control on _LayOut.cshtml
<h2>@Html.Label("lbl_PageCaption", Convert.ToString(ViewBag.PageTitle))</h2>

This is the DashBoard Controller where on Index Method I am setting ViewBag.PageTitle

ViewBag.PageTitle = "Dash Board";

Now What I need When I am on DashBoard Page, then I need my Layout Controller Text should 'DashBoard'.
Thanks....

Comment: Solution you have suggested works when I am on the same Controllers View but here I want to Change the Text of Controller on Master Page. In Asp.net We use Master Page Reference on Child Page then we can easily Change the Text, but how do i do same in MVC... Hope you understood the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. You make BaseViewModel class with that prop, set _Layout's model as this type and derive other models from it. Now you can access that prop from any derived model
2. You use ViewBag or ViewData
3. You make a @section in Layout view and populate it within Controller's views

If you need Layout's fields in many controllers then usage of #1 looks preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Why does not use this simple approach:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Name = "...";
    Layout = "_Layout.cstml";
}
```

And in your layout set your lable text with `@ViewBag.Name`

Answer (score 0):

**Layout**

```
<label>@ViewBag.Label</label>
```

Then just assign a value to ViewBag.Label in your controllers,  and it will automatically change.

```
public ActionResult OtherPage() 
{
   ViewBag.Label = "Other Label";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Solution you have suggested works when I am on the same Controllers View but here I want to Change the Text of Controller on Master Page.
>   In Asp.net We use Master Page Reference on Child Page then we can
>   easily Change the Text, but how do i do same in MVC... Hope you
>   understood the scenario. –*

If you look at what is generated when you start a new project with the "Internet Template" in MVC 4, you have a way to do it already working for you:

In the  element of _Layout, look for `<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>`, then in all the different views, you have something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
```

All you need to do is to move/duplicate ViewBag.Title out of the HEAD intot the BODY, or create your own ViewBag variable, and set it's values from your different views. Obviously you could just as well set the value from the controller, but I don't see the need, as this really has to do exclusively with the user interface, which is the Views job.

Finally, if I may, don't try to duplicate in MVC what you're used to with ASP.NET. The paradigms are way too differents, chances are that you are going to waste time while there might be an easy MVC way to achieve the same thing.

It seems to me this is just an example of it.....